# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, f5

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 
'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

when trying to connect to my MySQL server.

What I am doing:

- I have Master - Slave replication in MySQL that is working and just added load balance capabilities using F5.
- I have configured the F5 according to their site.

But when I am trying to connect to my MySQL server using the IP that the F5 was configured with I get

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 
'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

Any ideas?

---

Update on my progress : **ZERO**
- i am getting the same error 
I get no entries in the /var/log/secure as if somebody would try to authenticate coming form the ip where i had created my load balance server.
No enties in the mysql error log.
The command - returns nothing

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aborted_connections';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I've already altered my `my.cnf` file and add the

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

Alterd the `connect_timeout` to 10.
 So it seems i get no response for the server i have created on my F5 
I finally convinced the F5 admin to pass me the log for the F5 server and i have exctraced all i need form it.
**Here is the output :**

```
  Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <CLIENT_ACCEPTED>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- clientside initial connection
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <CLIENT_ACCEPTED>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- clientside responding with server WELCOME packet
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <CLIENT_DATA>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- clientside authenticated flag not set
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm err tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <CLIENT_DATA>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- mysql client: attempting to do something before authentication
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <LB_SELECTED>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- serverside selected pool /Common/foss-mysql-slave_pool node SLAVE-IP
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <CLIENT_CLOSED>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- clientside connection closed from MASTER-IP(XXXXXXX)
Jan 28 15:46:39 tmm debug tmm[6459]: Rule /Common/iRule-f5_mysql_proxy <SERVER_CLOSED>: BIG-IP MySQL Proxy -- serverside connection closed from node SLAVE-IP(XXXXXXXX)
```

I've replaced the ip for security sake !

**just as an extra** - and i think is here the problem - my mysql version is **5.1.69-log**
Thx All

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**From documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html):

> More rarely, it can happen when the client is attempting the initial
>   connection to the server. In this case, if your connect_timeout value
>   is set to only a few seconds, you may be able to resolve the problem
>   by increasing it to ten seconds, perhaps more if you have a very long
>   distance or slow connection. You can determine whether you are
>   experiencing this more uncommon cause by using SHOW STATUS LIKE
>   'aborted_connections'. It will increase by one for each initial
>   connection attempt that the server aborts. You may see “reading
>   authorization packet” as part of the error message; if so, that also
>   suggests that this is the solution that you need.

Try increasing **connect_timeout** in your **my.cnf** file

***Another style:***

**MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'**

1. At some point, it was impossible for remote clients to connect to
   the MySQL server.
2. The client (some application on a Windows platform) gave a vague
   description like `Connection unexpectedly terminated`.
3. When remotely logging in with the MySQL client the following error
   appeared:

   `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

On FreeBSD this happens because there was no match found in `/etc/hosts.allow.` Adding the following line before the line saying `ALL:ALL` fixes this:

```
mysqld: ALL: allow
```

On non-FreeBSD Unix systems, it is worth to check the files `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny.` If you are restricting connections, make sure this line is in `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
mysqld: ALL
```

or check if the host is listed in `/etc/hosts.deny.`

In Arch Linux, a similar line can be added to `/etc/hosts.allow`:

```
mysqld: ALL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... ```/etc/hosts.allow``` line helped me.

Answer (score 10):

This is usually caused by an aborted connect. You can verify this by checking the status:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aborted_connects';
```

If this counter keeps increasing as you get the lost connections, that's a sign you're having a problem during connect.

One remedy that seems to work in many cases is to increase the timeout.  A suggested value is 10 seconds:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL connect_timeout = 10;
```

Another common cause of connect timeouts is the reverse-DNS lookup that is necessary when authenticating clients.  It is recommended to run MySQL with the config variable in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

This means that your GRANT statements need to be based on IP address rather than hostname.

---

I also found this report from 2012 at the f5.com site (now protected by login, but I got it [through Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aA8NsbHHSFIIJ%3ahttps://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.MySQL-Proxy.ashx?Discuss=1%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us))

> It is likely the proxy will not work unless you are running BIG-IP 11.1 and MySQL 5.1, which were the versions I tested against. The MySQL protocol has a habit of changing.

I suggest you contact [F5 Support](https://f5.com/support/product-support) and confirm that you are using a supported combination of versions.

Comment: it shows me 0 aborted connection- ive set the connect_timeout already - and the skip-name-resolve already set !

Comment: will look into that link thx ! it might be the version of my mysql rdbms, hope so kkkkk

Answer (score 9):

I've struggled a lot with this error. Tried every single answer I found on the internet.

In the end, I've connected my computer to my cell phone's hotspot and everything worked. I turned out that my company's internet was blocking the connection with MySQL.

This is not a complete solution, but maybe someone faces the same problem. It worths to check the connection.

Comment: I performed Network Reset on my laptop, connected to another hot-spot connection and it worked.

Comment: thanks for reminding me of company's corporate network

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by stopping mysql several times.

```
$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxx.local.pid).
$ mysql.server stop
Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS! 
$ mysql.server stop
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found! (note: this is good)
$ mysql.server start
```

All good from here. I suspect mysql had been started more than once.

Answer (score 3):

My case was that the server didn't accept the connection from this IP. The server is a SQL server from Google Apps Engine, and you have to configure allowed remote hosts that can connect to the server.

Adding the (new) host to the GAE admin page solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have a mac but would assume all linux are the same for this part...

In my case I got this:

```
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Start server: 
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Server start done.
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Checking server status...
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0 (2013)
2018-12-03 11:13:27 - Assuming server is not running
```

I ran this:

```
sudo killall mysqld
```

And then started the mysql again through mysqlworkbench although in your case it might be like this:

```
mysql.server start
```

*sidenote: I tried running `mysql.server stop` and got this `Shutting down MySQL
.... SUCCESS!` but after running `ps aux | grep mysql` I saw that it hasn't really shut down...

Answer (score 2):

I use several mysql connections (connecting to different sets of databases) in localhost.

This happened to me after I shut my computer down and mysql was not properly shutdown. After starting my machine I was able to successfully connect to multiple db connections except one (I used this a lot before my machine shutdown).
As per the instructions in this posts I doubled connect_timeout but I was not able to connect to that one database connection.

I restarted my machine and i can successfully connect now. This will help you unblock yourself but it'd be great if it can be fixed without restarting the machine.

Another concern is: connection_timeout seemed to me delay related problem but I was getting the error immediately in localhost when there is no network in the equation.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it happened when there were a lot of connection to the MySQL server (15,000 connections) and the free memory was about 120M . After I added more memory to the server, the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I scratched my head about this error for 3 days.  I tried tweaking permissions on the database, new users from different IPs in the Users table, adjusting the bind-address in a bunch of different ways, comparing my my.cnf file to a known working server, firewall changes, upstream firewall changes, hosts.allow/deny...none of them worked.

Then I looked not at mysql/error.log (which came up empty) but my journalctl -xe log and low and behold, it couldn't read my /etc/hosts.allow and my /etc/hosts.deny file.

chmod 644 hosts.allow
chmod 644 hosts.deny.

All better now.

Comment: where is this hosts.allow files ?

Comment: Usually in /etc.  if it isn’t there, create it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility can be connection reset from the TCP wrappers (/etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow). Just check what is coming in from the telnet to port 3306 - if it is nothing, then there is something is in the middle preventing communication from happening.

Comment: It was the mysql version ! the loadbalancer code was not supporting the running client version ! :(

Answer (score 1):

I've created my account just to add this bit of information to this old question, because nowhere on the web I found any reference to the cause of my problem which I eventually found.

(Adding it here cause this is the top google result, also when adding PHP as search term)

**In PHP 7.4 when you fork a process (I know, who does this??) that has an active MySQL connection, the connection will get messed up and spit out the OP's error.
just reinitialize/recreate the connection in each forked process after the forking, this will fix it.**

Hope it this helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I got both errors: mostly `reading initial communication packet` *and* `reading authorization packet` one time. It seems random, but sometimes I was able to establish a connection after reboots, but *after some time* the error creeped back.

*Avoiding the 5GHz WiFi in the client seems to have fixed the issue.* That's what worked for me (server was always connected to 2.4GHz).

I tried everything from server versions, odbc connector versions, firewall settings, installing some windows update (and then uninstalling them), some of the answers posted here, etc... lost my entire sleep time for today. Super tired day awaits me.

Answer (score 0):

**In my case I was facing this `Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0` error while connecting with RDS mysql cluster in private subnet using this below command with correct credentials on ec2 instance**

[image]

Finally, I fixed it by adding the VPC IP address in RDS Security Group inbound rule hopefully it will work for you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by changing `my.ini` file, essentially changing the max allowed packet size in Mysql and changed timeout time to 30 seconds.

```
connect_timeout = 30
max_allowed_packet = 500M
```

Answer (score -3):

If you get this when using DevDesktop - just restart DevDesktop!