# Connecting to MySQL via SSH ERROR 2013 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, mediatemple

#### The Setup

I am currently using the Premium Wordpress Hosting provided by MediaTemple. I have a very large data-set to import and I was hoping to get direct access to the database via an SSH tunnel.

```
---------------                      -------------------               ------------
| My Machine  | ---- SSH TUNNEL -----| Hosting Server  | -- -- ? -- -- | Database |
---------------                      -------------------               ------------
```

#### What Works

If I ssh into the `Hosting Server` and from the **shell on the** `Hosting Provider`, connect to mysql like this, I am able to get into MySQL.

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -h123.456.789.1 -P3308
```

#### What Does Not Work

However, if I try to connect to MySQL using the -L flag with SSH to create a tunnel, I am unable to connect to the server.

```
 ssh me@hostingserver.net  -L 7002:123.456.789.1:3308
```

**From a shell on** `My Machine`:

```
 mysql -uuser -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -P7002
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

From reading other answers ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091850/error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-authorization-pa) , [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578147/mysql-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communic)), I have reasoned that the issue stems from the IP address with which MySQL client tries to bind. I think that the ip address attach to the request to connect, when executed on my machine, is not on the white-list of the `Database Server`.

Is there anyway to get direct access to the MySQL Database from `My Machine`. From a system administration perspective, I obiviously have enough access to connect to the MySQL database from the shell but I cannot run the client on `My Machine`. I have a very large dataset that I would like to transfer from `My Machine` to `Database`. I would also like to be able access the database and exicute SQL whenever I need to. This and the large dataset kind of eliminates  the possibility of just using a the `source` command from the MySQL Client on `Hosting Server`. What is the best workaround to give me something close to the ability to run SQL on the `Database` from `My Machine`?

Comment: this might help http://serverfault.com/a/136792

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't think I have direct SSH access to the Database Server.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered roughly the same issue. That is, I simply could not connect to the MySQL server, even though I had successfully tunneled to the remote host.

**TLDR:** it was an `iptables` issue involving the loopback interface

In my situation, `mysqld` was running on the same VPS as `sshd`. However, the MySQL instance was bound only to `127.0.0.1` and listening on the default port. As you did, I confirmed that I could connect to the `mysqld` instance on the remote machine using the credentials used locally.

Here is the tunnel:

`ssh -v -N -L 33306:127.0.0.1:3306 sshuser@sshanddbvps.org`

Here is the connection string to the `mysqld` instance using the `mysql` client:

`mysql -umysqluser -h127.0.0.1 -P 33306 -p`

Even though `ssh` indicated that the connection was successful...

`debug1: Connection to port 33306 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 3306 requested.`

...the `mysql` client connection would error out after accepting the correct password with the message you mentioned:

`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'...`

To check that data was flowing across the loopback interface, I logged into the remote server and ran three commands in three separate shells:

1. `while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234; done`
2. `tcpdump -i lo src 127.0.0.1 -or dst 127.0.0.1`
3. `nc 127.0.0.1 1234`

After running the third, output from the second command appeared:

`13:59:14.474552 IP localhost.36146 > localhost.1234: Flags [S], seq 1149798272, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 48523264 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

But nothing indicating that packets were flowing in the reverse direction.

Inserting a rule in the `INPUT` chain of the firewall that allowed traffic from the default loopback address solved the issue:

`iptables -I INPUT 4 -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Thank you for your description - it saved my day :) I believe the the last line should run iptables, not tcpdump, right?

Comment: @dimril Yes, thanks for catching that! I've just corrected it.

Comment: to avoid iptables: Index of insertion too big:
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT