# How to connect with MySQL from R?

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to connect with MySQL from R (version R-3.3.3). Unfortunately, I get the error. I tried to change the version to R-3.4.0 but the error is persistent.

```
 library(DBI)
 library(RMySQL)

 db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "example", host = "localhost", 
               port = 3306, user = "root", 
               password = "****")
```

> Error: Error in .local(drv, ...) :  Failed to connect to database:
>   Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at  'reading authorization
>   packet', system error: 10060

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091850/error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-authorization-pa

Comment: Those instructions are for Unix system. I am using Windows. Sorry, I must have clarified that before

Comment: Where is your MySQL server situated? Since you use localhost it seems to be same machine you are running R. Do you successfully connect with other tools like phpmyadmin? Or the command line: MySQL.exe?

Comment: I tried opening MySQL.exe (mysql -u root -p -host localhost. I got following error: Unknown mysql server host 'ost' <0>

Comment: Yes, something is faulty about your installation. Since this is not a programming issue, try asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/. But before asking try making an effort, maybe un-install/re-install (backing up data files).

Comment: Thank you. I will remove and reinstall MySQL again. Lets see if it works.