# Cant connect to Azure MySQL through MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database, azure, mysql-workbench, azure-sql-database

I have set up an Azure SQL server and database. In the dashboard, I am selecting the SQL Database to copy the server name (`xxxxxx.database.windows.net`).

I am creating a new connection in MySQL workbench and putting this servername as host.
The port I am putting is 1433.
After entering username and password, I am testing the connection. I am getting the following error, as the connection is not getting established between my database/server on Azure and workbench. The error is:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error:104
```

Any suggestions on making me understand why is it happening and how can the connection be made will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could be a firewall issue, also take a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091850/error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-authorization-pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is confusing, are you using Azure SQL Database or Azure Database for MySQL? **The name format "xxxxxx.database.windows.net" is for Azure SQL Database, which you should not use MySQL workbench to connect.** I'd suggest you switch to SSMS and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I realised it. I am using Fedora so SMSS was not an convenient option. I finally connected to the SQL database using DBeawer through ODBC connection.