# MySql can't open more than one client

Tags: mysql, macos

I can't open more than one MySQL connections at the same time in my Mac OS.
For example if I connect to a database using Sequel Pro and then I go to Terminal and try to connect to MySQL I get this error:

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 102

And of course the problem occurs also the other way around even in my websites. If I open MySql using Sequel or Terminal my local websites can't connect to MySQL.

S.O => Mac Os El Capitan
MySQL => 5.7.9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091850/error-2013-hy000-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-authorization-pa

Answer (score 0):

Increasing connect_timeout in *my.cnf* file helped me in exactly the same situation. I've just added `connect_timeout 30` to *my.cnf* file

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not fix my problem. Actually, I just copied the conf example from "my-default.cnf" added the connect_timeout = 30 without success.

Comment: If it is your local machine try to use MySQL8 if you can.. May be it helps.. Not the best solution, but have no other idea

Comment: I will update to Mojave and MySQL8... maybe I will have luck this time.